# Logging in python with correct timezone

Tags: python, logging

I would like to write log in a file with the correct timezone time (Europe/Paris) in a UpdateSubsStatus.log file ...

Here what i tried, the commented line are what i tired but it does not work.

```
import pytz

class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    """override logging.Formatter to use an aware datetime object"""
    def converter(self, timestamp):
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
        tzinfo = pytz.timezone('America/Denver')
        return tzinfo.localize(dt)
        
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        dt = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = dt.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            try:
                s = dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
            except TypeError:
                s = dt.isoformat()
        return s
#console = logging.StreamHandler()
logging.basicConfig(filename='UpdateSubsStatus.log', filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s;%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#console.setFormatter(Formatter)
#logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

Does it exist a simple way with the basic config to use a timezone ?

Regards

Comment: Shouldn't Python be using the system-wide time zone by default for `%(asctime)`? Try setting the system-wide time zone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried logging events using your code. the events are logged in the local timezone, not the specified one. I think the problem is with this code

```
def converter(self, timestamp):
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    tzinfo = pytz.timezone('America/Denver')
    return tzinfo.localize(dt)
```

This code converts timestamp to local datetime and changes tzinfo without a real datetime conversion

```
>>> timestamp
1619258964.3946261
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 24, 13, 9, 24, 394626)
>>> tzinfo = pytz.timezone('America/Denver')
>>> res = tzinfo.localize(dt)
>>> res
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 24, 13, 9, 24, 394626, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Denver' MDT-1 day, 18:00:00 DST>)
# Hours left unchanged
```

So I change method `converter`

```
def converter(self, timestamp):
    # Create datetime in UTC
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=pytz.UTC)
    # Change datetime's timezone 
    return dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Denver'))
```

Here the final code

```
import pytz
import logging
import datetime


class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    """override logging.Formatter to use an aware datetime object"""

    def converter(self, timestamp):
        # Create datetime in UTC
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=pytz.UTC)
        # Change datetime's timezone
        return dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Denver'))

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        dt = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = dt.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            try:
                s = dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
            except TypeError:
                s = dt.isoformat()
        return s


console = logging.FileHandler('UpdateSubsStatus.log')
console.setFormatter(Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s;%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
logging.critical("Critical event")
```

Log file `UpdateSubsStatus.log` (still `America/Denver` timezone)

```
2021-04-24 04:19:16;root - CRITICAL - Critical event
2021-04-24 04:19:17;root - CRITICAL - Critical event
```

Also, don't forget to change the timezone to `Europe/Paris`

Comment: I'd suggest ovvriding the __init__ of the Formatter class to pass the timezone rather than hard coding it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This helps, just using simple logic and passing in the required Timezone as an argument. Also, the return value is created with dateTimenow format.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def getTime(timeZoneVal):
    # get the standard UTC time
    UTC = pytz.utc
    logTime = pytz.timezone(timeZoneVal)

    #print("US Time in Default Format : ",  datetime.now(logTime))
    return datetime.now(logTime)

logTime = getTime('Europe/Paris')
print(logTime)
```